# Tkinter entry to be an integer

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a GUI with Tkinter to allow someone to enter one string and two integers which would then run a code when a button was pressed to extract data from one file to another but I keep getting an issue and I'm not sure how to get around it.

```
def copy(Orn, Orc, Stage):
    for a in range(1, 10):
        for b in range(1,Stage):

import Tkinter as T
top= T.Tk()
L1=T.Label(text="Order Number").grid(row=0, column=0)
E1=T.Entry().grid(row=0,column=1)
L2=T.Label(text="Number of Compounds").grid(row=1,column=0)
E2=T.Entry().grid(row=1,column=1)
L3=T.Label(text="Number of Stages").grid(row=2,column=0)
E3=T.Entry().grid(row=2, column=1)
B1=T.Button(text="Extract", command=copy(E1, E2, E3)).grid(row=3,column=0)
top.mainloop()
```

I get the error `range() integer end argument expected, got NoneType.` How do I get the entry value to be an integer? I also tried:

```
e3=E3.get()
```

as was shown in someone's similar question but then I get the error: `NoneType object has no attribute get.` What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in using **E3.get()** to get the Entry widget value. But the error `NoneType object has no attribute get` is the result of putting your Grid statement on the same line as your widget creation. Always separate the two. So use

```
E3 = T.Entry()
E3.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

Otherwise it sets the value of your widget to the None because that's what the Grid statement returns.

Comment: Thank you so much that moves me on to the next error I get. 'e3=int(E3.get())' gives me 'invalid literal for int() with base 10.' I tried 'float' and I get 'could not convert string to float.'

Comment: @zw1ck Im not entirely sure what is getting put into the box, but that error is likely due to there being a space in the string. Use .strip() to get rid of any white space and then convert that to an int.

Comment: I'm not sure where you integer conversion is happening, but it's likely due to `command`. When assigning functions to widgets you have to drop the `()` and use `command=function`, however if you want to pass variables you need to use `lambda` like so `command=lambda: function(a, b, c)`. If you don't do it like so and use `command=function()` or `command=function(a, b, c)` then it will be called instead of assigned. Which is why you are getting the error, because you can't convert empty string to int (since entry is empty).